# Paypal Payments Pro & Credit Card Subscriptions

Tags: paypal

I am developing a PHP site where you can sign up to a subscription with an initial amount.

I am using the PayPal NVP api as it seems the most comprehensive.

Setting this up with a PayPal user is fine. I am also trying to set this up for credit/debit cards.

When testing in the sandbox I keep getting the following response:

> DPRP is disabled for this merchant

I have enabled BUSINESS-pro in the sandbox account as it suggests but I am still getting the error.

There seems to be lots of conflicting information in the developer documentation/ web searches that this functionality is still available for the NVP api service.

If not, can someone point me towards the correct solution or API reference to enable me to do this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use DPRP for sandbox account, you need to contact PayPal technical team to enable it, just submit a ticket at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/ (click contact support at the bottom), someone will toggle the function for you.

Comment: Thanks very much, browsed the site before but didn't see the tiny contact us link. Someone from PayPal tech support has been in touch to hopefully resolve it.